# How to use the same heap for DLL and EXE in Visual C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, dll, dllexport

I'm developing a shared engine library to use it in different apps. But when I made DLL and linked it to an app, it started to fail with different memory errors.

As I understood different DLL and EXE heaps causes that. Look at screenshot:
[image]

The object I need is in square brackets, but I cannot access it from application. The same story is for DLL.

How I can make it to use the same heap or access directly these objects?

There're no any same errors on linux or mac, when I'm building shared libraries and using them in app. Just in Windows I don't know how to get it normally working. I'm sure, that using static libraries is not such good in this case, but I should to find a solution how to get it working peacefull.

Code, where error occurs (that is another example, which I resolved. The error above occurs when I'm getting object from this hierarchy, it is existent, but in different worlds):

```
if (EditorInstance::GetSingleton()->currentScene->hierarchy->empty())
```

Where hierarchy is:

```
boost::container::list<GameObject*>
```

in `Scene` class.

I'm initializing list in constructor, but when I'm trying to use it in app it is uninitialized. The hack which partially resolved this problem is getter, that returns hierarch: GetHierarchy().
But for whole object there's no such hack...

Now I can get object from hierarchy, but as shown in screenshot, it points to 2 different objects, one of which is defined as I did, and accessible from DLL, and one which is undefined (I can define it immediately before using in app, otherwise it will be existent only for DLL objects.)
DLL object is in sqare brackets, app object is root.

Comment: "different DLL and EXE heaps causes that" - no, it is an error in your code that is causing that. `cdcdcdcd` looks like a debug pattern for uninitialized memory

Comment: Just throw the error you get at a websearch, that pattern is easily found online with further info.

Comment: Make sure you link with the DLL version of the runtime library (as opposed to the static version).

Comment: @VTT you can see that it is uninitialized to an app, the [GameObject] is initialized for DLL. I did this initialization, even twice.

Comment: @PaulSanders I'm compiling it with /MD key. Of course.

Comment: Just checking :)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'm already did this a lot of times. No soultion for my trouble. I can access data from inside the constructor, and from nearest objects which also belongs to DLL, but from main process it says that the object is not initialized. But the same address for both object(s), from inside itself and from app.

Comment: @VTT according to your judgement, `this` can be also uninitialized. But why the result depends on that, from where it is called?

Comment: Since you didn't provide [mcve] it is not possible to tell exactly what is going on in this case. It can be anything from stack corruption to ODR violation. Also note that initialization can not be performed more than once and both dll and executable and all their data are all inside of a single process.

Comment: @VTT Sorry. Check this: https://github.com/ExQDev/NukeEngine/blob/master/src/API/Model/GameObject.cpp
And this: https://github.com/ExQDev/NukeEngine-Editor/blob/11e49d024caf426e2b748384a4fc27603ac05e40/main.cpp#L88

I can access gameObject's name from EditorInstance, AppInstance and Scene, but cannot from Editor.

Comment: A link to a whole project doesn't work, also you need to reduce this. Extract a [mcve] (read that carefully!) and then [edit] your question to put that inline. Concerning the pattern, I didn't want to suggest that you find a solution to your problem, only that you find an explanation of where that pattern comes from.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I tried as much I could, cannot provide more detailed description, cause a lot of binded code. Sorry.

Comment: You can reduce it by creating a very simple DLL and a very simply EXE and having the DLL allocate some memory from the heap and the EXE free it. If you can get that to work, then you can try to transfer the solution to your main project.

Answer (score 0):

The main of my mistakes was that I have pushed to list the pointer to object, which was destroyed later (GC?).

I have created this object under the predicate, and after exiting from `if` it was cleared, and pointer that I passed to list was wiped.

```
if(something){
    GameObject* newObject = new GameObject();
    ...
    hierarchy.push_back(newObject);
}
```

Is it right?